# List concurrency failing

Tags: java, android, multithreading, list, concurrency

I have an Arraylist that I am constantly adding to and removing from in separate threads.
One thread adds, and the other removes.

This is the class that contains the changing list:

```
public class DataReceiver {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "DataReceiver";

    // Class variables
    private volatile ArrayList<Byte> buffer;
    //private volatile Semaphore dataAmount;

    public DataReceiver() {
        this.buffer = new ArrayList<Byte>();
        //this.dataAmount = new Semaphore(0, true);
    }

    // Adds a data sample to the data buffer. 
    public final void addData(byte[] newData, int bytes) {
        int newDataPos = 0;

        // While there is still data
        while(newDataPos < bytes) {
            // Fill data buffer array with new data
            buffer.add(newData[newDataPos]);
            newDataPos++;
            //dataAmount.release();
        }

        return;
    }

    public synchronized byte getDataByte() {
/*
        try {
            dataAmount.acquire();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            return 0;
        }
*/
        while(buffer.size() == 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(250);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "getDataByte: failed to sleep");
            }
        }

        return buffer.remove(0);
    }
}
```

The problem is I get a null pointer every so often exception when trying to `buffer.remove(0)`.  As you can tell form the comments in the code, I tried using a semaphore at one point but it still intermittently threw nullpointer exceptions, so I created my own type of sleep-poll as a semi-proof-of-concept.

I do not understand why a null pointer exception would occur and/or how to fix it.

Comment: You need to add the data first, before removing it. size() only indicates the number of elements present in the List. You cannot remove elements if they do not exist in the List.

Comment: Why not just use one of the `java.util.concurrent` classes? It seems like a [`LinkedBlockingDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Can you add client code that exposes the problem?

Comment: Please share the stack trace for the exception.

Comment: Sleeping inside of a synchronized method does not seem like a good idea.

Comment: I accepted the answer below because it is probably the cause of my problems, but now that the `java.util.concurrent` classes has been pointed out by @MattiasBuelens, I will definitely be taking advantage of those.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a guess as to an explanation.  I would do it in comments, but I don't have enough reputation, so hopefully this answer is helpful.

First of all, if you were to declare the addData() function as synchronized, would your problem go away?  My guess is that it would.

My theory is that although you declared buffer as volatile, that is not sufficient protection for your use case.  Imagine this case:

- addData() gets called and is calling buffer.add()
- at the same time, getDataByte() is checking buffer.size() == 0

My theory is that buffer.add() is not an atomic operation.  Somewhere during the buffer.add() operation, it's internal size counter increments, enabling your getDataByte() call to buffer.size() == 0 to return false.  On occasion, getDataByte() continues with its buffer.remove() call before your buffer.add() call completes.

This is based on an excerpt I read here:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/
"While the increment operation (x++) may look like a single operation, it is really a compound read-modify-write sequence of operations that must execute atomically -- and volatile does not provide the necessary atomicity."

Answer (score 1):

If you are handling the object initialization in a different thread it is possible that the constructor is not finished before the

```
 public synchronized byte getDataByte()
```

is called therefore causing the `NullPointerException` because

```
this.buffer = new ArrayList<Byte>();
```

was never called.

Comment: +1 : this is the most likely cause, but without a stacktrace and client code it's really impossible to determine the exact cause.